# Fails to load image after 1min and 22sec

Tags: c++, image, load, sdl

I'm making a simple space-invaders-like game in c++ using sdl2. Things were going super. The game worked fine, until, I noticed that SDL fails to load any of my PNGs after about 1min and 22sec. It just stops working for whatever reason. I tried for hours to find similar issues, but without any luck. (I'm quite new to game-developing and graphical programming in general).

**main.cpp :**

```
 #include "SpaceInv.h"


int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    SpaceInv si;
    si.StartGame();
    return 0;
}
```

**SpaceInv.h:**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SPACEINV
#define SPACEINV
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "SpaceContainer.h"
#include "ScoreBoard.h"

class SpaceInv {
public:
    SpaceInv();
    ~SpaceInv();
    void StartGame();
    void Close();
    bool Initialize();
    SDL_Texture* LoadTexture(std::string file);
    void generateEnemy();
    void generateAsteroid();
    bool checkCollitions(SDL_Rect& a, SDL_Rect& b);
    int randNum(int min, int max);
private:
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 720;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* background = NULL;
    Ship ship;
    ScoreBoard score;
    int frameWidth, frameHeight;
    int textureWidth, textureHeight;
    SpaceContainer lazers;
    SpaceContainer explosions;
    SpaceContainer enemyLazers;
    SpaceContainer asteroids;
    SpaceContainer enemyShips;  

};

#endif
```

**SpaceInv.cpp :**

```
    #include "SpaceInv.h"
#include "Asteroid.h"
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <random>


SpaceInv::SpaceInv(){
}
SpaceInv::~SpaceInv(){}

void SpaceInv::StartGame() {
    if (!Initialize()) {
        printf("Could not initialize!\n");
        return;
    }

    //load background music
    Mix_Chunk *bgm = Mix_LoadWAV("bgm.wav");
    Mix_Chunk *lazerBeam = Mix_LoadWAV("Lazerbeam.wav");

    if (!bgm) {
        std::cout << "no music found..." << std::endl;
    }
    Mix_PlayChannel(0, bgm, 0);

    if (bgm==NULL) {
        std::cout << "no music found..." << std::endl;
    }

    background = LoadTexture("img.png");
    ship.setSpriteName("ship.png");
    ship.setTexture(renderer);

    score.setTexture(renderer, "Score: 0");


    int points = 0;
    const int FPS = 60;
    int frameTime = 0;

    bool exit = false;


    while (!exit) {

        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {

            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT || e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                exit =  true;
            }

            if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {


                if (e.key.keysym.sym==SDLK_LEFT){
                    ship.moveX(-1); //std::cout << "left";
                }
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT){
                    ship.moveX(1); //std::cout << "Right";

                }
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP){
                    ship.moveY(-1); //std::cout << "UP";
                }
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN){
                    ship.moveY(1); //std::cout << "DOWN";
                }
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE && e.key.repeat==0) {
                    //skapa laser om input = SPACE 
                    SpaceObject lazer("lazer.png", ship.getPos(), 5, 10);
                    lazer.setSpriteName("lazer.png");

                    int x = ship.getPos().x;
                    int y = ship.getPos().y - 20;

                    lazer.setPos(x , y);
                    lazer.setTexture(renderer);
                    lazers.pushBack(lazer);
                    Mix_PlayChannel(1, lazerBeam, 0);
                    //std::cout << "SPACE";
                }
            }

        }

        frameTime++;
        if (FPS / frameTime == 4) {
            frameTime = 0;

            //animate ship
            ship.animate();

            //animate lazers
            for (size_t i = 0; i < lazers.size(); i++) {
                lazers.getObject(i).animate();
            }

            //animate asteroids
            for (size_t i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++) {
                asteroids.getObject(i).animate();
            }

            //animate enemy lazers
            for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyLazers.size(); i++) {
                enemyLazers.getObject(i).animate();
            }

            //animate enemy ships
            for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyShips.size(); i++) {
                enemyShips.getObject(i).animate();
            }

            //animate explosions
            for (size_t i = 0; i < explosions.size(); i++){
                explosions.getObject(i).animate();
            }

        }

        //random generate asteroids
        if (randNum(1, 100) >= 99) {
            generateAsteroid();
        }
        //random generate enemy ships
        if (randNum(-200, 200) >= 199) {
            generateEnemy();
        }

        //make enemy ships fire at random
        for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyShips.size(); i++){
            if (randNum(0, 200) >= 199) {
                SpaceObject enemyLazer("lazer.png", enemyShips.getObject(i).getPos(), 5, -10);
                enemyLazer.setSpriteName("lazer.png");
                enemyLazer.setTexture(renderer);
                enemyLazers.pushBack(enemyLazer);
                Mix_PlayChannel(i+2, lazerBeam, 0);
            }
        }
        //clear the renderer
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        //render ship and background image
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, ship.getTexture(), &ship.getRect(), &ship.getPos());

        //rendrer scoreboard
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, score.getTexture(), NULL, &score.getPos());

        //uppdate and render lazers
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lazers.size(); i++) {

            lazers.getObject(i).moveY();
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, lazers.getObject(i).getTexture(), &lazers.getObject(i).getRect(),
                &lazers.getObject(i).getPos());
        }

        //uppdate and render asteroids
        for (size_t i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++) {
            asteroids.getObject(i).moveY();
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, asteroids.getObject(i).getTexture(), &asteroids.getObject(i).getRect(),
                &asteroids.getObject(i).getPos());
        }

        //uppdate and render enemy lazers
        for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyLazers.size(); i++) {
            enemyLazers.getObject(i).moveY();
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, enemyLazers.getObject(i).getTexture(), &enemyLazers.getObject(i).getRect(),
                &enemyLazers.getObject(i).getPos());
        }

        //uppdate and render enemy ships
        for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyShips.size(); i++) {
            enemyShips.getObject(i).moveY();
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, enemyShips.getObject(i).getTexture(), &enemyShips.getObject(i).getRect(),
                &enemyShips.getObject(i).getPos());
        }

        //render explosions
        for (size_t i = 0; i < explosions.size(); i++) {

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, explosions.getObject(i).getTexture(), &explosions.getObject(i).getRect(),
                &explosions.getObject(i).getPos());
        }

        //look for collisions between lazers and enemy ships
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lazers.size(); i++) {

            for (size_t j = 0; j < enemyShips.size(); j++) {
                if (checkCollitions(lazers.getObject(i).getPos(), enemyShips.getObject(j).getPos())) {

                    //std::cout << "collision!!" << std::endl;
                    lazers.getObject(i).setTimeToLive(0);
                    enemyShips.getObject(j).setTimeToLive(0);

                    SpaceObject explosion("explosion.png", enemyShips.getObject(j).getPos(), 1, 0);
                    explosion.setSpriteName("explosion.png");
                    //lazer.setPos(ship.getPos());
                    explosion.setTexture(renderer);
                    explosions.pushBack(explosion);

                    points += 10;
                }
            }
        }

        ////look for collisions between lazers and asteroids
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lazers.size(); i++) {

            for (size_t j = 0; j < asteroids.size(); j++) {
                if (checkCollitions(lazers.getObject(i).getPos(), asteroids.getObject(j).getPos())) {

                    //std::cout << "collision!!" << std::endl;
                    lazers.getObject(i).setTimeToLive(0);
                    asteroids.getObject(j).setTimeToLive(0);

                    SpaceObject explosion("explosion.png", asteroids.getObject(j).getPos(), 1, 0);
                    explosion.setSpriteName("explosion.png");
                    //lazer.setPos(ship.getPos());
                    explosion.setTexture(renderer);
                    explosions.pushBack(explosion);

                    points += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        ////look for collisions between ship and asteroids
        for (size_t i = 0; i < asteroids.size(); i++) {

            if (checkCollitions(ship.getPos(), asteroids.getObject(i).getPos())) {

                //exit = true;

            }
        }

        ////look for collisions between ship and enemy lazers
        for (size_t i = 0; i < enemyLazers.size(); i++) {

            if (checkCollitions(ship.getPos(), enemyLazers.getObject(i).getPos())) {

                //exit = true;

            }
        }

        //check the lifetime of every object on the screen.
        enemyShips.checkLifetime();
        enemyLazers.checkLifetime();
        asteroids.checkLifetime();
        lazers.checkLifetime();
        explosions.checkLifetime();

        //update score
        score.setTexture(renderer, "Score: " + std::to_string(points));

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }
    Close();

    return;
}

bool SpaceInv::Initialize() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO)) {
        printf("SDL could not be initialized! SDL Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);
        return false;
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Super Space Wars Extreme",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);
        return false;
    }
    //screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == NULL) {
        printf("Not able to create renderer! SDL Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);
        return false;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if (!IMG_Init(imgFlags & imgFlags)) {

        printf("SDL_image could not be initialized! SDL_image Error %s\n", IMG_GetError);
        return false;
    }

    if (TTF_Init() == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Init TTF  failt : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    /*if (Mix_Init() == -1) {
        std::cout << "Audio Error : " << Mix_GetError() << std::endl;
    }*/

    if(Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0){
        std::cout << "Audio Error : " << Mix_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    return true;

}
SDL_Texture* SpaceInv::LoadTexture(std::string file) {

    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(file.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load image! SDL_image Error %s\n", file.c_str(), IMG_GetError);
    }
    else {
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
        if (newTexture == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to create the texture from %s! SDL_image Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);

            SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
        }
    }
    return newTexture;

}

void SpaceInv::generateAsteroid() {
    SpaceObject asteroid(20, -randNum(1,5));  //TODO kolla livslängd
    asteroid.setSpriteName("asteroid.png");

    asteroid.setTexture(renderer);

    asteroid.setPos(randNum(0, SCREEN_WIDTH) , -200);
    asteroid.makeEnemy();
    asteroid.changeSpriteSize(8, 8, 128);

    asteroids.pushBack(asteroid);
}

void SpaceInv::generateEnemy() {
    SpaceObject enemy(20, -2);  //TODO kolla livslängd
    enemy.setSpriteName("enemyship.png");

    enemy.setTexture(renderer);

    enemy.setPos(randNum(0, SCREEN_WIDTH), -200);
    enemy.makeEnemy();


    enemyShips.pushBack(enemy);
}

int SpaceInv::randNum(int min, int max) {
    int output = min + (rand() % static_cast<int>(max - min + 1));

    return output;
}


bool SpaceInv::checkCollitions(SDL_Rect& a, SDL_Rect& b) {
    //The sides of the rectangles
    int leftA, leftB;
    int rightA, rightB;
    int topA, topB;
    int bottomA, bottomB;

    leftA = a.x;
    rightA = a.x + a.w;
    topA = a.y;
    bottomA = a.y + a.h;

    leftB = b.x;
    rightB = b.x + b.w;
    topB = b.y;
    bottomB = b.y + b.h;
    if (bottomA <= topB) {
        return false;
    }

    if (topA >= bottomB) {
        return false;
    }

    if (rightA <= leftB) {
        return false;
    }

    if (leftA >= rightB) {
        return false;
    }

    //If none of the sides from A are outside B
    return true;
}

void SpaceInv::Close() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;

    Mix_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**SpaceObject.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SPACEOBJECT
#define SPACEOBJECT

#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

class SpaceObject {
public:
    SpaceObject();
    SpaceObject(double t, int sp);
    SpaceObject(std::string s, SDL_Rect startPos, double t, int sp);
    ~SpaceObject();
    double getDuration();
    double getTimeToLive();
    void setSpriteName(std::string s);
    void setTimeToLive(int i);
    std::string getSpriteName();
    void setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer);
    SDL_Texture*& getTexture();
    SDL_Rect getRect();
    SDL_Rect* getRectP();
    SDL_Rect getPos();
    void setPos(int x, int y);
    void moveY();
    void animate();
    void makeEnemy();
    void changeSpriteSize(int a, int b, int c);
    bool isEnemy();
protected:
    //int test;
    std::string spriteName;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect sprite;
    SDL_Rect pos;
    int speed;
    int frameWidth, frameHeight;
    int textureWidth, textureHeight;
    bool enemy = false;
    bool asteroid = false;
    bool lazer = false;
    double timeToLive;
    double duration;
    std::clock_t start;
};

#endif
```

**SpaceObject.cpp**

```
 #include "SpaceObject.h"
    #include <iostream>

SpaceObject::SpaceObject(){}

SpaceObject::SpaceObject(double t, int sp):timeToLive(t), speed(sp) {
    start = std::clock();
    enemy = false;
}

SpaceObject::SpaceObject(std::string s, SDL_Rect startPos, double t, int sp) : spriteName(s), timeToLive(t), pos(startPos), speed(sp) {
    //pos.y = pos.y - 27;
    start = std::clock();
    enemy = false;
}
SDL_Rect* SpaceObject::getRectP() {
    return &sprite;
}
void SpaceObject::makeEnemy() {

    enemy = true;
}
void SpaceObject::changeSpriteSize(int a, int b, int c){
    frameWidth = textureWidth / a;
    frameHeight = textureHeight / b;
    sprite.w = frameWidth;
    sprite.h = frameHeight;

    sprite.h = sprite.w = c;
}
bool SpaceObject::isEnemy() {
    //enemy = false;
    ////std::cout.setf(std::ios::boolalpha);
    ////std::cout << enemy << std::endl;
    return enemy;
}
void SpaceObject::setTimeToLive(int i) {
    timeToLive = i;
}
void SpaceObject::setPos(int x, int y) {
    pos.x = x;
    pos.y = y;
}

SDL_Rect SpaceObject::getPos() {
    //pos.y = pos.y - 5;
    return pos;
}

double SpaceObject::getTimeToLive() { return timeToLive; }
std::string SpaceObject::getSpriteName() { return spriteName; }

void SpaceObject::setSpriteName(std::string s) {
    spriteName = s;
}



void SpaceObject::setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer) {
    ////std::cout << spriteName << std::endl;
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(spriteName.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load image! SDL_image Error %s\n", spriteName.c_str(), IMG_GetError);
    }
    else {
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
        if (newTexture == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to create the texture from %s! SDL_image Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);

            SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
        }
    }
    texture = newTexture;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &textureWidth, &textureHeight);

    frameWidth = textureWidth /2;
    frameHeight = textureHeight /2;
    //sprite.x = 0;
    //sprite.y = 0;
    sprite.w = frameWidth;
    sprite.h = frameHeight;

    pos.w = pos.h = 64;



}

SDL_Rect SpaceObject::getRect() {
    return sprite;
}

void SpaceObject::animate() {
    sprite.x += frameWidth;

    if (sprite.x >= textureWidth) {

        sprite.x = 0;
        sprite.y += frameHeight;

        if (sprite.y >= textureWidth) {
            sprite.y = 0;
        }
    }
}



void SpaceObject::moveY() {
    pos.y = pos.y - speed;
}


double SpaceObject::getDuration() {
    duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return duration;
}
SDL_Texture*& SpaceObject::getTexture() { return texture; }
SpaceObject::~SpaceObject() { ////std::cout << "Rymdobjekt borttaget" << std::endl; 
}
```

**Ship.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SHIP
#define SHIP
// "Lazer.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
//#include "SpaceInv.h"

class Ship {
public:
    Ship();
    Ship(std::string s);
    ~Ship();
    void setSpriteName(std::string s);
    std::string getSpriteName();
    void setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer);
    SDL_Texture*& getTexture();
    void animate();
    SDL_Rect getRect();
    SDL_Rect getPos();
    //SDL_Texture*& Ship::fire(int speed, SDL_Rect start, SDL_Renderer* &renderer);
    //void fire(int speed, SDL_Rect start);
    void moveX(int speed);
    void moveY(int speed);



private:
    std::string spriteName;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect sprite;
    SDL_Rect pos;
    int frameWidth, frameHeight;
    int textureWidth, textureHeight;
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 720;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


};

#endif
```

**Ship.cpp**

```
#include "Ship.h"
//#include "Lazer.h"
Ship::Ship(){}

Ship::Ship(std::string s):spriteName(s){}


std::string Ship::getSpriteName() { return spriteName; }

void Ship::setSpriteName(std::string s) {
    spriteName = s;
}

SDL_Texture*& Ship::getTexture(){ return texture; }

void Ship::setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer) {

    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(spriteName.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load image! SDL_image Error %s\n", spriteName.c_str(), IMG_GetError);
    }
    else {
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
        if (newTexture == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to create the texture from %s! SDL_image Error %s\n", SDL_GetError);

            SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
        }
    }
    texture = newTexture;

    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &textureWidth, &textureHeight);


    pos.w = pos.h = 64;
    pos.x = 340;
    pos.y = 255;

    frameWidth = 192 / 2;
    frameHeight = 192 / 2;
    sprite.x = 0;
    sprite.y = 0;
    sprite.w = frameWidth;
    sprite.h = frameHeight;
}

SDL_Rect Ship::getRect() {
    return sprite;
}

SDL_Rect Ship::getPos() {
    return pos;
}

void Ship::moveX(int speed){
    if ((pos.x <= 0 && speed<0) || (pos.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH && speed>0)) {
        //std:://std:://std::cout << "/n";
        return;
    }
    pos.x = pos.x +speed*(SCREEN_WIDTH/20);
}

void Ship::moveY(int speed) {
    if ((pos.y <= 0 && speed<0) || (pos.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT && speed>0)) {
        return;
    }
    pos.y = pos.y + speed*(SCREEN_WIDTH / 20);
}

void Ship::animate() {
    sprite.x += frameWidth;

    if (sprite.x >= textureWidth) {

        sprite.x = 0;
        sprite.y += frameHeight;

        if (sprite.y >= textureWidth) {
            sprite.y = 0;
        }
    }
}
/*
SDL_Texture*& Ship::fire(int speed, SDL_Rect start, SDL_Renderer* &renderer) {
    Lazer lazer("lazer.png", start);
    lazer.setTexture(renderer);
    return lazer.getTexture();

}*/

Ship::~Ship() {}
```

**SpaceContainer.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SPACECONTAINER
#define SPACECONTAINER
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "SpaceObject.h"
//#include "SpaceInv.h"

class SpaceContainer {
public:
    SpaceContainer();
    ~SpaceContainer();
    SpaceObject& getObject(int i);
    std::vector<SpaceObject>& getVec();
    void checkLifetime();
    void pushBack(SpaceObject o);
    void popAt(int i);
    bool checkCollitions(SDL_Rect& a, SDL_Rect& b);

    size_t size();



private:
    std::vector<SpaceObject> vec;
};

#endif
```

**SpaceContainer.cpp**

```
#include "SpaceContainer.h"

SpaceContainer::SpaceContainer(){}

void SpaceContainer::checkLifetime(){
    if (vec.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            ////std::cout << vec[i].getDuration() << std::endl;
            if (vec[i].getDuration() >= vec[i].getTimeToLive()) {
                vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
            //  delete &vec[i];
                ////std::cout << "Object destroyed " << std::endl;
            }
        }
}

void SpaceContainer::popAt(int i) {
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
}

void SpaceContainer::pushBack(SpaceObject o) {
    vec.push_back(o);
}

SpaceObject& SpaceContainer::getObject(int i) {
    return vec.at(i);
}
std::vector<SpaceObject>& SpaceContainer::getVec() {
    return vec;
}


size_t SpaceContainer::size(){
    return vec.size();
}

SpaceContainer::~SpaceContainer(){}
```

**ScoreBoard.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SCOREBOARD
#define SCOREBOARD
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>


class ScoreBoard {
public:
    ScoreBoard();
    void setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, std::string mes);
    SDL_Texture*& getTexture();
    SDL_Rect getRect();
    SDL_Rect getPos();
    ~ScoreBoard();

private:
    SDL_Rect sprite;
    SDL_Rect pos;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
};

#endif
```

**ScoreBoard.cpp**

```
#include "ScoreBoard.h"
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
ScoreBoard::ScoreBoard(){}

SDL_Texture*& ScoreBoard::getTexture() { return texture; }

SDL_Rect ScoreBoard::getRect() {
    return sprite;
}

SDL_Rect ScoreBoard::getPos() {
    return pos;
}

void ScoreBoard::setTexture(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, std::string mes) {
    TTF_Font* Sans = TTF_OpenFont("FreeSansBold.ttf", 24); 
    SDL_Color White = { 255, 255, 255 };  

    if (!Sans) {
        std::cout << "font not found..." << std::endl;
        return;
    }


    const char * c = mes.c_str();
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Sans, c, White);

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

    pos.w = 128;
    pos.h = 64;
    pos.x = 15;
    pos.y = 5;

}

ScoreBoard::~ScoreBoard(){};
```

I'm sorry that the code is not that beautiful. (It contains some console output and stuff for debugging + some out-commented objects that are no longer used). Any suggestions on why my game stops working? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: You are probably leaking resources, like opening files without closing them or loading textures every frame without freeing them. Eventually the OS will not let you have more resources. Try to make a [mcve] to get a higher chance someone reads through the code properly.

Comment: Thanks! I look into that! The thing is.. I dunno what causes the problem, so I thought i needed to post the entire project !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nwp 3's comment, I solved it! The problem was indeed that my program was asking for to much resources. By calling "SDL_DestroyTexture(SDL_Texture* texture)", inside my SpaceContainer class, everytime a SpaceObject was destroyed, the problem was fixed!

**SpaceContainer.cpp**

```
#include "SpaceContainer.h"

SpaceContainer::SpaceContainer(){}

void SpaceContainer::checkLifetime(){
    if (vec.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            if (vec[i].getDuration() >= vec[i].getTimeToLive()) {

                //here was the issue!!
                SDL_DestroyTexture(vec[i].getTexture());
                vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);

            }
        }
}

void SpaceContainer::popAt(int i) {
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
}

void SpaceContainer::pushBack(SpaceObject o) {
    vec.push_back(o);
}

SpaceObject& SpaceContainer::getObject(int i) {
    return vec.at(i);
}
std::vector<SpaceObject>& SpaceContainer::getVec() {
    return vec;
}


size_t SpaceContainer::size(){
    return vec.size();
}

SpaceContainer::~SpaceContainer(){}
```